# Sudden change in the url on click of new button click

Tags: lightning-web-components, url

I am facing a issue all of sudden. I have two object Lead and Estimate. Estimate comes in related list of Lead. From Lead i can create new estimate. I created a LWC component which is used to create new Estimate records. LWC component i have embedded in aura component. I developed related LWC 3 months back, on click of new button aura component is getting loaded first which loads LWC. In Aura controller i have tried to fetch recordId(lead Id) which was appearing in url using below code

````
component.set("v.estimateid", component.get("v.recordId"));
    var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
    console.log(' PageREf'+JSON.stringify(pageRef));
    var state = pageRef.state; // state holds any query params console.log('state = '+JSON.stringify(state));
    var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef; 
    console.log('base64Context = '+base64Context); 
   
        if (base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) 
        {
            base64Context = base64Context.substring(2); 
            console.log('base64Context = '+base64Context);
        }
        var addressableContext = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Context));
        console.log('addressableContext = '+JSON.stringify(addressableContext));
        component.set("v.recordId", addressableContext.attributes.recordId);```
````

This code was giving me LeadId from url. But from 3/4 days i am getting error when aura component is loaded.  I tried to debug issue i observed change in URL. Previously a different URL was opening on click of new button which was holding lead id but now a days a different URL is appearing hence aura is not able to get leadId from url.

I dont have exact URL but it was roughly like

```
https://.../lightning/o/VLSF_Estimate__c/new?inContextOfRef=1.eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RhbmRhcmRfX29iamVjdFBhZ2UiLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7Im9iamVjdEFwaU5hbWUiOiJWTFNGX0VzdGltYXRlX19jIiwiYWN0aW9uTmFtZSI6Imxpc3QifSwic3RhdGUiOnsiZmlsdGVyTmFtZSI6IlJlY2VudCJ9fQ%3D%3D&count=1%2FLead%2F00Q1g000005oxHBEAY%2Fview
```

But now when i click new url i am getting is

```
https://.../lightning/o/VLSF_Estimate__c/new?count=1
```

Please help me to understand what can be the reason behind change in onload URl..

Comment: what do each of the console logs indicate? could you add more details as to what you see and what you'd expect?

Comment: I wanted to  know the code I written previously based on url I was receiving .. but now I am receiving some other url when I click on new button in related list estimate..I mentioned url in my question..